# dbpedia sparql endpoint character encoding

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I have a problem with the [DBpedia SPARQL endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql).
When I call this query it doesn't return any results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * WHERE {
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Santiago_Bernabéu_Stadium> rdfs:label ?label . 
  OPTIONAL {
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Santiago_Bernabéu_Stadium> geo:lat ?lat ;
                                                            geo:long ?long .
  }
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT+DISTINCT+%2a+WHERE+%7B%0D%0A++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FSantiago_Bernab%C3%A9u_Stadium%3E+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Flabel+.+%0D%0A++OPTIONAL+%7B%0D%0A++++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FSantiago_Bernab%C3%A9u_Stadium%3E+geo%3Alat+%3Flat+%3B%0D%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++geo%3Along+%3Flong+.%0D%0A++%7D%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

But when I change the URL to something like `<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Sierra_Nevada_(Spain)>` it works perfectly.  I call it from Java using Apache Commons HttpClient (tried with POST and GET).
I think the problem is in `é` with accent, but I can´t find any encoding solving my problem.  Do you know how could I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks I found the answer.
Using URLEncoder was not solution as long it was changing other characters (like braces).
But I've found that I should use URIref class from Jena.
Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem updating the jena library. Search and and use the last version of all jar files. For example, I was using jena-2.6.3 and now I am using jena-arq-2.9.3.jar, jena-core-2.7.3-test.jar, jena-2.7.3.jar, jena-iri-0.9.3.jar, etc.